# Issues with Rails models associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a cart and items table associated to themselves but when I query the cart table and includes the Items table. It is querying the items table with the cart id instead of the items_id.

Below is my code:

Migration:

```
class Carts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :carts do |t|
      t.references :user, foreign_key: true
   t.references :items, foreign_key: true,
     t.timestamps
   end
  end
end
```

Model:

```
class Cart < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
 has_many :items, :foreign_key => "id"
end
```

controller:

```
def index
        @items = Cart.includes(:items).where(user_id: current_user.id)
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the assocations backwards. To setup a one-to-many association between carts and items you need to place the foreign key on items table - not carts as that would only allow a 1-1 assocation. `references` just creates a integer column that can hold a single id.

[image: Db design sketch]

You can create the correct migrations with `rails g model cart user:references` and `rails g model item cart:references`. If simply rolling back and doing it over is not an option then you need to write migrations to add `cart_id` to the `items` table and to remove `items_id` from the `carts` table.

```
class Cart < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :items # references items.cart_id
end

class Item < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :cart # items.cart_id
end

class User
  has_many :carts
  has_many :items, through: :carts
end
```

Although to create a typical web shop you want three tables:

[image: Typical web shop db schema]

```
class Cart < ApplicationController
  has_many :line_items
  has_many :products, though: :line_items
end

class LineItem < ApplicationController
  belongs_to :cart
  belongs_to :product
end

class Product < ApplicationController
  has_many :line_items
  has_many :carts, though: :line_items
end
```

Comment: There are plenty of other problems with the code in the question. `@items = Cart.includes(:items).where(user_id: current_user.id)` will return carts - not items.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly you want items by user and cart, so your code is wrong and i thing you misunderstood ActiveRecord `.includes`.

You querying `Cart` by `user_id` in :

```
@items = Cart.includes(:items).where(user_id: current_user.id)
```

The `.includes` here only allows you to access the items of the `Cart` model without firing an additional query

To get items you should :

```
 # With know cart id
 @items = Item.where(cart_id: cart_id)

 # With only user id (for example)
 # Querying all items where cart have current user id
 @items = Item.join(:cart).where(carts: { user_id: current_user.id })
```

[Active Record .includes Documentation](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes)

[Active Record .joins Documentation](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/joins)

Comment: Thank you, So what I am trying to do is fetch all cart items that belong to a particular user then include the details of each Items from the Items table since I am only adding `user_id` and `items_id` in the carts table.

Comment: @dealwap,whatever the code you have written  is correct ( Cart.includes(:items).where(user_id: current_user.id)), but,you have done the wrong association.See the  max's answer.In this answer also, the cod will  work only if you  place the foreign key on items table  not on carts table